# Filtering by date in Shiny

Tags: r, date, shiny, filtering

cannot resolve a simple task as a poor Shiny guy.

I have a row in a data frame with dates

```
crime.date <- strptime(incidents$REPORT_DAT, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

My output for dates looks like this.

```
[1] "2017-04-07 EDT" "2017-03-13 EDT" "2017-01-08 EST" "2017-01-25 EST" "2017- 
01-03 EST" "2017-01-03 EST" "2017-01-03 EST"
[8] "2017-01-03 EST" "2017-01-03 EST" "2017-01-03 EST" "2017-01-03 EST" "2017-
01-04 EST" "2017-01-03 EST" "2017-01-03 EST"
```

Now I try to visualize the selection of all crimes, chosen by this filter.

```
# USER INTERFACE CODE

ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Washington, DC crimes by date"),

column(4, wellPanel(
dateRangeInput('dateRange',
               label = 'Filter crimes by date',
               start = crime.date , end = crime.date
)
)),
column(6,
     verbatimTextOutput("dateRange")
)
)

# SERVER CODE

server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$dateRangeText  <- renderText({
paste("input$dateRange is", 
      paste(as.character(input$dateRange), collapse = " to ")
)
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I believe that my mistake is somewhere between start and end because I put their only crime.date variable.

What do I want? I want to select start and end date and receive all incidents, which happened during this period (output as a text is fine for now).

Any help is MUCH APPRECIATED.

Thanks

Oleksiy

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To filter your dataframe, we can use the line

```
incidents %>% filter(REPORT_DAT >= input$dateRange[1] & REPORT_DAT <= input$dateRange[2])
```

within a `renderDataTable` statement. A working example is given below. Note that since you did not include sample data, I created some sample data myself.

Hope this helps!

---

[image]

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

# Sample data
incidents = data.frame(REPORT_DAT=c('2018-01-01','2018-02-01','2018-03-01','2018-04-01','2018-05-01'))
# Convert character to Date
incidents$REPORT_DAT =  as.Date(incidents$REPORT_DAT, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Washington, DC crimes by date"),

  column(4, wellPanel(
    dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                   label = 'Filter crimes by date',
                   start = as.Date('2018-01-01') , end = as.Date('2018-06-01')
    )
  )),
  column(6,
         dataTableOutput('my_table')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$my_table  <- renderDataTable({
      # Filter the data
      incidents %>% filter(REPORT_DAT >= input$dateRange[1] & REPORT_DAT <= input$dateRange[2])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```