# shiny filter overlapping user supplied dates with dataset dates

Tags: r, shiny, lubridate

I've a simple task in shiny that I cant work out. I'm trying to filter dates (following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848841/filtering-by-date-in-shiny)) in a dataframe if the intervals between two dates overlap those chosen by the user. Essentially I'm trying to implement the following function in two parts - one that will 1. filter the data and 2. also tell the user the `tally` of ids between the intervals somewhere on screen in a separate area:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(date1 = seq.Date(from =as.Date("1997-01-01"), 
                                  to=as.Date("1997-01-07"), by="day"),
                 date2 = seq.Date(from =as.Date("1997-01-03"), 
                                  to=as.Date("1997-01-09"), by="day"),
                 id = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b",4)))
df
       date1      date2 id
1 1997-01-01 1997-01-03  a
2 1997-01-02 1997-01-04  a
3 1997-01-03 1997-01-05  a
4 1997-01-04 1997-01-06  b
5 1997-01-05 1997-01-07  b
6 1997-01-06 1997-01-08  b
7 1997-01-07 1997-01-09  b
```

my basic function to compute if user dates overlap those in dataset (and also tally them by distinct id) is:

```
my_interval <- function(date_from, date_to) {
  df2 <- df %>%
    mutate(tmp_interval = as.integer(int_overlaps(interval(date1, date2), 
                                                  interval(as.Date(date_from), as.Date(date_to))))) %>%
    filter(tmp_interval == 1) %>%
    distinct(id) %>%
    ungroup() 
  x <- c("The number of IDs between ", date_from, " and ", date_to, " was ", tally(df2))
  return(paste(x, collapse = ""))
}
my_interval("1997-01-03", "1997-01-05")
#"The number of IDs between 1997-01-03 and 1997-01-05 was 2"
```

If I want to first just filter the data in shiny, the following returns an error `unused argument (input$dateRange[2])`

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("test"),

  column(4, wellPanel(
    dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                   label = 'Filter overlapping dates',
                   start = as.Date('1997-01-01') , end = as.Date('1997-03-01')
    )
  )),
  column(6,
         dataTableOutput('my_table')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$my_table  <- renderDataTable({
    df %>%
      mutate(tmp_interval = as.integer(int_overlaps(interval(date1, date2), 
                                                    interval(input$dateRange[1]), input$dateRange[2]))) %>%
      filter(tmp_interval == 1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any suggestions to fix (and improve) the code is welcome. Also, I'm wondering is this the best way to find overlapping dates, its slow to run on only 70000 rows.

Comment: You second call to `interval` is at fault. The parenthesis after `input$dateRange[1]` should be after `input$dateRange[2]`. As is `input$dateRange[2]` is understood as an (unnamed) argument to `int_overlaps`, which is why you get that error.

Comment: ah fresh eyes,thought there was more to it, thanks!